# Find string patterns enclosed in specific characters (PHP)

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a HTML template (as a single string) that contains a various number of keys enclosed in ### characters. For instance, these keys could be ###textItem1###, ###textItem2### and so on ...

Now, how do I find all keys that are enclosed in ### in that HTML template/string? I want to read the keys, save them in an array and then loop through the array in order to replace the keys by a proper text item (that is also represented by the same key, but in another array).

I'm working with PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use a regular expression or some good str (php) command to achieve that

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions with PHP's `preg_match_all` function:

```
$pattern = '/###(.+?)###/';
$string = 'This is a text with ###textItem1### and ###textItem2### in it. It also has ###textItem3### and ###textItem4### as well';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

PHPFiddle Link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/psad-tq9r

Answer (score 1):

This Works too.

```
    $string = 'hello, this is [@firstname], i am [@age] years old';
    preg_match_all('~\[@(.+?)\]~', $string, $matches);
    var_dump( $matches );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function like this

```
 function getdatabetween($string, $start, $end){
        $sp = strpos($string, $start)+strlen($start);
        $ep = strpos($string, $end)-strlen($start);
        $data = trim(substr($string, $sp, $ep));
        return trim($data);
    }


echo getdatabetween(" ###textItem1###","###", "###");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `preg_match_all`

for example this is your template code

```
<?php
$string = '
<html>
<head>
<title>###title###</title>
</head>
<body>
###content###
</body>
</html>
';
```

and this is the data that you want to replace

```
$data = array("title" => 'hello world', 'content' => 'Page content here ....');
```

you can replace it like this

```
function getTemplate($string, $data){
   preg_match_all("/[###]{3}+[a-z0-9_-]+[###]{3}/i", $string, $matches);
   foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $match) {
       $string = str_replace($match, $data[str_replace('#', '', $match)], $string);
   }

   return $string;
}

echo getTemplate($string, $data);
```

output

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
Page content here ....
</body>
</html>
```